# 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'contact_no'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am facing a problem whenever i tried to fill my form and field Contact no & Phone no it automatically generate its own static no. every time and as i had given "UNIQUE" to my key 'Contact_no' it generates error this "

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key
>   'contact_no'' in C:\wamp\www\ipsem6\connectivity.php:34 Stack trace:
>   0 C:\wamp\www\ipsem6\connectivity.php(34): PDO->exec('INSERT INTO a8...') #1{main}`"

Below is my code of my register.php page

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Register</title>
<style>

.content:before {
content: "";
position: fixed;
left:34px;
right:0;
top:90px;
bottom:20px;
z-index: -1;

display: block;
background-image: url('assets/img/cd.JPG');
width: 1281px;
height: 8000px;


-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
}

.content {
overflow: auto;
position: static;

left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
}

</style>
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style/fg_membersite.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'></script>
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style/pwdwidget.css" />
<script src="scripts/pwdwidget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style1.css" type="text/css" />    
</head>
<body   class="body" >
<div class="content">
<header class="mainheader" >

<div class="canmenu">

<div class="left mtop10"><a href="http://www.chitkara.edu.in/" title=""     rel="home">
<img src="assets/img/chitkara_logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
   <div id="cssmenu">
        <nav><ul>
           <li><a href="index.html"><span><b>Home</b></span></a></li>

           <li><a href="#"><span><b>About Us</b></span></a></li>

           <li><a href="login.html"><span><b>Login</b></span></a></li>

           <li class="active"><a href="register.php"><span><b>Register</b> </span></a></li>

           <li class="last"><a href=""><span><b>Contact us</b></span></a></li>
        </ul></nav>
    </div>

    <!--<div class="can-menu">
                </div>-->
</div>
</div>
<!-- Form Code Start -->

<center><div id='fg_membersite' >
<form id='register'  method='post' action="connectivity.php" accept-charset='UTF-8' >

<br>
<br>


<fieldset >

<legend><h1><font size="40" color="BLACK"><b><center><img src="assets/img/canfinal1.jpg" height="100px" width="150px"/><font color="WHITE">Register</font></b></font></h1></legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

<div class='short_explanation'><font size="2" color="RED"><b>* required fields</b></font></div>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip'  />

<div><span class='error'> </span></div>
<div class='container'>
<label for='name' ><font color="WHITE">Your Full Name<font color="RED"><b>*</b></font> :</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name'  maxlength="50" /><br/>
<span id='register_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
<label for='email' ><font color="WHITE">Email Address<font color="RED"><b>*</b></font> :</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email'  maxlength="50" /><br/>
<span id='register_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
<label for='username' ><font color="WHITE">UserName/University Id<font color="RED"><b>*</b></font> :</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" /><br/>
<span id='register_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container'>
<label for='contacts1' ><font color="WHITE">Contact No.<font color="RED"><b>*</b></font> :</label><br/>
<input type='phone' name='contacts1' id='contacts1'   /><br/>

</div>

<div class='container'>
<label for='contact2' ><font color="WHITE">Phone No. :</label><br/>
<input type='tel' name='contact2' id='contact2'   /><br/>

</div>


<div class='container' >
<label for='password' ><font color="WHITE">Password<font color="RED"><b>*</b></font> :</label><br/>
<div class='pwdwidgetdiv' id='thepwddiv' ></div>
<noscript>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
</noscript>    
<div id='register_password_errorloc' class='error' style='clear:both'></div>
</div>





<div class='container'>
<label for='date' ><font color="WHITE">Date of Birth<font color="RED"><b>*</b></font> :</label><br/>
<input type='date' name='dats' id='dats'  maxlength="50" /><br/>
<span id='register_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container' >
<label><font color="WHITE">Role<font color="RED"><b>*</b></font> :</label>
<select  name='rle' id='rle'  maxlength="50" >
<option value="Alumni">Alumni</option>
<option value="Mentor">Mentor</option>
<option value="H.O.D">H.O.D</option>

</select>
 <span id='register_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>


</div>

<div id="q1" class="form-group">
<label><font color="WHITE">Gender<font color="RED"><b>*</b></font> :</label>
<select class="form-control"  id="s" name="s">
<option value="Male" >Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</div>
</select>



<div class='container'>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' color="blue" />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
<!-- client-side Form Validations:
Uses the excellent form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
// <![CDATA                                                                                         
var pwdwidget = new PasswordWidget('thepwddiv','password');
pwdwidget.MakePWDWidget();

var frmvalidator  = new Validator("register");
frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name");

frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email address");



frmvalidator.addValidation("username","req","Please provide your University ID.");

frmvalidator.addValidation("password","req","Please provide a password");

frmvalidator.addValidation("date","req","Please provide your D.O.B");

// ]]>
</script>

<!--
Form Code End
-->

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is my code of connectivity.php

```
<?php
// DATABASE CONNECTIVITY & UPLOADING ----> 
$connection_error = 'Could Not Connect to server.';
$connection_error2 = 'Could Not Connect to database.';

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'a8172058_portal';
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database";
try {
   $conn = new PDO( $dsn, $user, $password );
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);




      $name=$_POST["name"];
      $email=$_POST["email"];
      $username=$_POST['username'];
      $pass=$_POST['password'];
      $contactno=$_POST['contacts1'];
      $cont2=$_POST['contact2'];
      $dob=$_POST['dats'];
      $role=$_POST['rle'];
      $gender=$_POST['s'];




       $sql= "INSERT INTO `a8172058_portal`.`users`  (email,univ_id,password,full_name,role,gender,contact_no1,contact_no2,dob) 
       VALUES   ('$email','$username','$pass','$name','$role','$gender','$contactno','$cont2','$dob');";

      $conn->exec($sql);
           print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=form1.html\">";
       }
            catch(PDOException $e)
             {
               print ($e);
               //print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
              }

             $conn = null;




  ?>
```

Please Help me solving this Problem . My DM is 
[image]

No matter what value i give it always give that static value marked in image below.
[image]

Comment: what is the type and length for both field? it happens because when number exceeds from the length given to that column. then it will automatically converted to some wired integer as you get. Once i faced it too.

Comment: contact_no1 = int(10) & contact_no2 = int(11)

Comment: change both to once in  `int(11)` or try once with `varchar(256)` for both column.

Comment: wow !! Thanx alot !! varchar(256) works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this type of problem occur when given number exceeds from the length of the corresponding column.

As you said that both column are `int(10) and int(11)`. So go for `varchar(256)`.

**Note:- Since it is phone number so you can go for `varchar` but if you have any integer on which you are going to do some calculation then go for `bigint`. Thanks.**

Comment: But int(11) didn't works and am adding phone no = 9530803237 !!

Comment: @AshishBharwal Yes i knew that's why i advise `varchar`

Comment: Ok got it !! Thanx again :) BIGINT(11) works also !!

Answer (score 3):

The number 2147483647 is the biggest ten-digit positive integer that can be stored in a 4 byte integer field.

You should use a larger field type like `BIGINT` although for this particular case I recommend `VARCHAR`. It's a phone number not an actual integer you need to do math with.

P.S: You should really use [pepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to protect your application from threats like SQL Injection. And you should always hash the password before inserting it in the database.

Comment: Thank You !! I got it !!

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem and it was caused regarding the statement binding method

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE user set UserName = ?, Password = ?, Email = ?, FullName = ? WHERE UserID = ?");      // i was forget 'WHERE' to check the registered data  so it always give me "fatal error" 'Duplicate data'
$stmt->execute(array($username, $pass, $email, $fullname, $id));
```